# Facebook url not allowed with web, works with cordova

Tags: facebook, facebook-oauth

We've got a combination phonegap/web app, and am trying to get facebook logins working.

Everything works fine with phonegap, but with the web, Facebook returns the familiar (to many) `Given URL is not allowed by the Application configuration...`

I've tried using localhost in the Facebook settings, as well as setting up a host on my local machine which used the same URL as our heroku development box (except it has https, which I don't, of course).

I didn't include the port number in the website with facebook login, when using the host as heroku, but tried both with and without on localhost.

Things I've tried

```
    locally - http:localhost:3000 // the app
on facebook
   website with facebook login -> http://localhost, http://localhost:3000
   app domains ->  localhost

locally - http://our-dev-site.herokuapp.com:3000 //the app
on facebook
   website with facebook login => http://our-dev-site.herokuapp.com, http://our-dev-site.herokuapp.com:3000
   app domains -> our-dev-site.herokuapp.com
```

I'm really not sure what else to try here. 
Is there somewhere in the facebook responses that they tell you what URL they are expecting?

-------------- update --------------------

I forgot that our javascript files are actually being served on another port number. The domain for the app is localhost:3000, but the javascript is served from localhost:8080. Not sure if this could be part of the problem.